# Does a Java based framework for data aggregation and reporting exist?

Tags: java, web-services, frameworks, reporting, aggregation

I'm about to commence working on an integration project that aims to gather data from several different application via SOAP, JSON etc. This data is then used for reporting.

Does a mature framework exist for this issue?
Or can anyone recommend a design pattern that would help to decouple the data fetching from the reporting?

Comment: It seems like the data farming and reporting are already naturally and physically decoupled.  Can you describe how consider these two coupled in your question?

Comment: I was looking something in the vein of a message bus. This bus could asynchronously connect data farming components to reporting components. This is because data is retrived from most applications by pulling but some push their data.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you look at the [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) project for the integration side of you requirements.

> "Spring Integration's primary goal is to provide a simple model for
>   building enterprise integration solutions while maintaining the
>   separation of concerns that is essential for producing maintainable,
>   testable code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/)? I never used it myself though...